# When there are multiple circuits in a junction box do all grounds get connected

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

If I have a junction box where there are splices from several circuits, do I connect all ground wires from all circuits together in one bundle or do I do that for each circuit within the junction box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one answer...  YES, all the bare grounds go together!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this OP got the right answer, at least under code in the US.  It's my understanding that of different circuits should not be connected together.

Comment: As I understand it NEC2014 allows for retrofitting a ground and that ground can go to any place that has one, even (as I understand it) if it's on a difference _circuit_ breaker. So, if you're covered by 2014, then yes, this is actually OK, at least for retrofits - I don't know about new installs.

Answer (score -3):

You connect all the grounds together with a ground crimp connector.  A wire nut is not sufficient to meet code.

And then if the box is metal, you connect the crimped bundle to the box.  Leave one of the ground wires longer than the others, sticking through the crimp connector, and attach that one to the box.

Comment: Ordinary wire nuts are acceptable for joining ground conductors: NEC 250.8(A) "Equipment grounding conductors... shall be connected by one of the following means: (1) Listed pressure connectors..."

Comment: I think the wire nuts vs crimp connector depends on your local inspector. In my case (Ohio) he said either is fine.